# python: read a file and match string in another file and pull out the lines

Tags: python, string, match

data 
masterfile :

```
192.168.42.2
192.68.42.12
```

searching file:

```
  1 17.248.154.203                           =>     7.88Kb     28.6Kb     28.6Kb     28.6KB
     192.168.42.12                            <=       208b      151Kb      151Kb      151KB
   2 a23-58-18-217.deploy.static.akamaitechn  =>     6.61Kb     8.60Kb     8.60Kb     8.60KB
     192.168.42.12                            <=     15.0Kb     4.95Kb     4.95Kb     4.95KB
   3 a23-207-129-216.deploy.static.akamaitec  =>         0b     8.09Kb     8.09Kb     8.09KB
     192.168.42.12                            <=         0b     3.25Kb     3.25Kb     3.25KB
   4 17.252.172.5                             =>         0b     4.92Kb     4.92Kb     4.92KB
     192.168.42.2                             <=         0b     3.73Kb     3.73Kb     3.73KB
     192.168.42.2                             <=         0b     3.73Kb     3.73Kb     3.73KB
```

**Desired ouput:**

192.168.42.12       3.25 (example)

192.168.42.2        3.73

[Link]https://pastebin.com/Ms4TyLMW   -- i have changed my code based on your suggestion

**This is what i got!**

'192.168.42.12              151

192.168.42.12               4.95

192.168.42.12              3.25

192.168.42.2               3.73

192.168.42.2               3.73

192.168.42.12              5.36

192.168.42.12               705'

@saul

How can i avoid printing this multiple same data.I am trying to  print same IP and corresponding usage in single line like this??

'192.168.42.12  2043(total usage of 192.168.42.12)

192.168.42.2    123(total usage of 192.168.42.2)'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your research and code you used to explain the problem.

Comment: unclear. what are the rules of matching?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the detailed input.Let me submit the condition and code what i have tried

Answer (score 0):

I have two IP address in a text file. First I need to read the IP address and then check the another file which is holding IP address with usage(please refer my question above).

Now I need to extract the corresponding the IP and usage from another file.
this code locate the particular position of IP and usage.
The problem is when I tried to iterate `iplist` it always takes the input of first data whichever is in the file. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
    for line in data_consumed:
        for element in iplist:
            if element in line:
                result = line
                ip = line[5:-50]
                result_ip = ip.replace(" ","")
                usage = line[-8:]
                d = usage.replace('KB', '')
                usage = d.replace('B','')
                usage = usage.replace('\n','')
                final_usage += float(usage)
                try:
                    final_usage += float(usage)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                megabyte = float(0.000976562)
                result_usage = megabyte * final_usage
        print result_ip + '\t\t\t' + str(result_usage)
```

**Desired output:**

```
192.168.42.12  usage(total value)

192.168.42.2  usage(totalvalue)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16305223)

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the code:

```
strStr = ["192.168.42.2", "192.168.42.12"]

# the "e:\temp\111.txt" is the searching file storage path.
with open(r"e:\temp\111.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ii in strStr:
        sumResult = 0
        for line in lines:
            if ii in line:
                sumResult += float(line.strip(" ").split(" ")[-1].split("KB")[0])
        print(ii, sumResult)
```

The code result is:

```
192.168.42.2 7.46
192.168.42.12 159.2
```

There are some question， because you don't finger out the match condition, just split the last value from the line data.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.But why it prints only for '192.168.42.2' and why not '192.168.42.12' values?
And please let me know what is the condition that you are expecting?

Comment: 1. You provided  the data is `192.68.42.12`, not the `192.168.42.12`, please check.
2. You provided the data sample `192.168.42.2                             <=         0b     3.73Kb     3.73Kb     3.73KB` , the 3.73 appeared 3 times, which value you want parse?

Comment: Oh sorry its my mistake(typo).Thanks after changing that it worked for me.
This is what i got!

Comment: Oh sorry its my mistake(typo).Thanks after changing that it worked for me.